# How to create a reactjs app with a specific scope

Tags: reactjs, npm, npx

Is it possible to create a react application with a specific scope?

this command : **npx create-react-app web1**

create this package.json:

```
{
  "name": "web1",
.....
}
```

I would like to know how to create it with a scope. **@myusername/web1**

```
{
  "name": "@myusername/web1",
.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, the create-react-app CLI takes the name input as a URL, so putting a '/' (or trying to escape it with '') will produce a folder structure.

Even if you do `npx create-react-app @myusername%2Fweb1` (%2f the encoding for urls for '/'), it won't work.